# reorder array without changing index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I'd like to sort an array without changing the index value. How can I achive this?

array:

```
let data = [];
data[12] = {"apples":1, "pears":2, "oranges":3};
data[25] = {"apples":3, "pears":3, "oranges":5};
data[18] = {"apples":4, "pears":1, "oranges":6};
```

I tried this:

```
function reorder(b, a) {
  return a - b;
}
```

but the output of reorder function is

```
data[0] = {"apples":3, "pears":3, "oranges":5};
data[1] = {"apples":4, "pears":1, "oranges":6};
data[2] = {"apples":1, "pears":2, "oranges":3};
```

and I'd like to achive something like this

```
data[25] = {"apples":3, "pears":3, "oranges":5};
data[18] = {"apples":4, "pears":1, "oranges":6};
data[12] = {"apples":1, "pears":2, "oranges":3};
```

Comment: The function is doing what expected... What you are expecting is not a sorting "I think" :) You are just "visually" sorting the array. I'm still curious to understand the real expected result. Why not using those old indexes as keys if their new "expected" order matters?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please explain your use case in more detail and the higher level problem you actually need to solve

Answer (score -1):

It seems you intend to sort the indexes. You can do it like this:

```
let data = [];
data[12] = {"apples":1, "pears":2, "oranges":3};
data[25] = {"apples":3, "pears":3, "oranges":5};
data[18] = {"apples":4, "pears":1, "oranges":6};

let keys = [];

for (key in data) keys.push(key);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < keys.length; j++) {
        if (keys[i] > keys[j]) {
            var aux = keys[i];
            keys[i] = keys[j];
            keys[j] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that

```
var newObject = {};
for (let key of keys) newObject[key] = data[key];
data = newObject;
```

will not necessarily change the order of the keys:

[image]

which means that if you intend to always iterate in a descendingly order, then you will need to iterate the `keys` as seen above in the order you prefer and use it to identify the current item.

Answer (score -1):

This would solve your problem, but please write what task I've just solved.

```js
let data = [];
data[12] = {"apples":1, "pears":2, "oranges":3};
data[25] = {"apples":3, "pears":3, "oranges":5};
data[18] = {"apples":4, "pears":1, "oranges":6};

let sorted = data
  .map((item, n)=>({ n, item, val: item.apples + item.pears + item.oranges }))
  .sort((a,b)=> a.val - b.val), i = 0;

data.forEach((item, n)=> data[n] = sorted[i++].item);
```